# I am not able to print the bar graph in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, data-visualization

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dslabs)
library(dplyr)
data("movielens")

movielens %>% top_n(10) %>% ggplot(aes(title, rating)) +
  geom_point()
```

I expect this code to give a bar chart like graph of 10 movies from the "movielens" data frame between the title of the movie and it's respective rating whereas,
this code is giving me an error like this:

```
Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `geom_bar(stat="identity")` if you intend to produce a bar plot with `ratings` for each `title`, because by default `stat="count"`

```
movielens %>% top_n(10) %>% ggplot(aes(title, rating)) +geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the answer from @Basti. You can also use the `geom_col()` which does the same as `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` just without having to explicity state it.

Ref: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html